# jQueryUI sortable to drag & drop columns in a responsive table

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to learn the jQueryUI sortable feature in order to make it work on a responsive table I'm using on my webpage.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLas15to/10/) to make some tests and I just can't figure out **how to drag and drop columns** (not only th's).

I suspected I should use the "connectWith" (or "items"?) option and connect all the td's that share the same id than the dragged th but I just don't succeed in doing that.

I'm not even sure that's what "connectWith" or "items" are made for actually but there is nothing else I can find in the documentation that seems to help me achieve a column drag & drop.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3</th> 
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                    <td>data 4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

 body:before{
     content: "";
     display: block;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    float:left;
}

tr{
    display:table-row;
    border: 1px solid black
}

th, td {
    border:1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}

th{
    position: relative;
    background:#bbb;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( function() {
    $('thead tr').sortable({
        start: function(e, ui)
        {
            var ind_th= ui.item.index();
            $('tbody td:nth-child('+(ind_th+1)+')').addClass('drg').css('color','red');
        },
        connectWith:".drg",
        stop: function(e, ui)
        {
            $('tbody td').removeClass('drg')
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly pretty, yet it will do the job.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7oyh9mj/53/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('thead tr').sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
    axis: 'x',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      var ind_th = ui.item.index();
      $('tbody tr').each(function(ind, el) {
        $('td', el).eq(ind_th).addClass('drg').css('color', 'red');
      });
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var itInd = ui.item.index();
      $("tbody tr").each(function(ind, el) {
        var cell = $(".drg", el).detach();
        cell.insertBefore($("td", el).eq(itInd));
        cell.removeClass("drg").css("color", "black");
      });
    }
  });
  $('thead tr').disableSelection();
});
```

You can also create your own helper using `function(event, element)`, yet it does not mesh well in `stop` or `update`.

So in `start`, I am adding the class `drg` to help identify the cells that will get moved. Once the `stop` is triggered, I use `.detach()` to remove them from the rows and then `insertBefore()` to place them back in the new position in the row based on the header index.

If you have a lot of data, I would advise looking at DataTables. I believe it offers this functionality.

**Update**

New Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7oyh9mj/72/

Two minor changes:

1. Removed `containment`; this was preventing header from dragging beyond table borders and could not be placed in the first position.
2. Add `if` for when drop point should be the last item

You can also adjust the `tolerance` options: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q7oyh9mj/73/

Your choice on how to manage it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, it has its issues: you can't get any column to be the first or last one. And if you try to make it the last one, the td's just disappear. It seems that "detach" only works well in between.
Bonus question if you don't mind: is there a simple way to have the td's shown In the placeholder as well?

Comment: I tried all the plugins I could find but they are messing a lot with my own functionalities in my tables. Trying to make them work is even harder for me than trying something simpler from scratch. This is why I'm trying to get the best of the simplest script I could find, so that I can build on top of it without compromising what I already have.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri updated my answer. Either remove `containment` or update `tolerance` to `pointer` to allow for placeholder to move to first column. Add an if statement for the end or last column.